# Ambiguity of "... is not to ..."

Tags: syntactic-analysis, ambiguity

> The purpose is not to dance like an elephant.

I see two ways of interpreting this sentence:

1. It is incorrect to say that "dance like an elephant" is the goal.
2. The objective is to prevent dancing like an elephant.

How should the sentence be re-written to avoid the ambiguity, if the desired meaning is (1) or (2), respectively?

---

Edit: perhaps I should give more context info about how this question came to me.

I want to write a document which should be referred to as a guideline rather than hard rules. I describe my intent with:

> The purpose of this document is not to enforce rules or regulations.

However, I want to avoid the interpretation "*the author wishes to stop enforcing rules and regulations*".

Comment: The sentence is totally ambiguous.  The "purpose" could be to elect a president, blow up a dam, write a poem, et al -- all are not dancing like an elephant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way to indicate unambiguously that "It is incorrect to say that "dance like an elephant" is the goal" is to reorder the sentence as

> Dancing like an elephant is not the purpose [or goal] of this exercise [or whatever].

One simple way to indicate that "The objective is to prevent dancing like an elephant" is to say

> The purpose [or goal] is to avoid dancing like an elephant.

Answer (score 3):

1. The purpose isn't to dance like an elephant.
2. The purpose is to not dance like an elephant.

Comment: (2) is ok. However, "isn't" is not a choice in formal writings, which, in this case, an operation document.

Comment: @kevin, in that case use the longhand "is not" . I would think that would be easily managed.